# Selenium System.getProperty (jenkins)

Tags: selenium, jenkins

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\opnGo\chromedriver.exe");

If i would like to add automation tests to automation server (Jenkins) , would System.getProperty work if certain path specified ? would appreciate some info.

Thank you

Comment: that'll get/set it for the Java runtime.  Are you working in Java here?

Comment: @pcalkins yeh Java

Answer (score 0):

If your Jenkins has many work nodes, put `chromedriver.exe` in the same path on these nodes machine, such as "C:\opnGo\chromedriver.exe". So that `System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\opnGo\chromedriver.exe");` will work.